# event.getSource() on `onclick` from <li>

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an iteration of `li`:

```
              <aura:iteration items="{!v.cities}" var="city">
              <li role="presentation"
                  class="slds-listbox__item"
                  onclick="{! c.doSomething }"
                  value="{! 500 }"
              >
              <!-- stuff in here -->
              </li>
              </aura:iteration>
```

As you can see there is an `onclick` event on list item **that works perfectly** but I need to send a value (set in the `value` from the markup).

When I am inside the callback `doSomething` I am **not** able to call `event.getSource()` to get the `li` element.

```
Event.getSource() is not a function
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to see the value directly from the event's target:

```
var value = event.target.value;
```

event.target is a SecureElement, which allows you to access most of the attributes of the element without allowing full DOM access.

Comment: That doesn't work anymore with LockerService enabled: Uncaught Action failed: one:centerStage$controller$handleDelegatedEvent [Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined]

Comment: @RobertSösemann That error looks like something different. Are you sure that's the cause?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I just went back and doublechecked. I do have value on my LI, and LS is enabled, and it still outputs the correct value, as expected.

Comment: I am using value on lightning:button as a replacement for the non-existing data-* there. I just get it via: event.getSource().get("v.value")

Comment: @RobertSösemann That's not the same issue as presented in this question. lightning:button is an aura:component, not a SecureElement. I suggest you ask a new question with your code, and we'll be glad to help you.

Comment: Ok I see. My question is here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176764.

Comment: @sfdcfox :  Now that LS is enabled compulsorily, I guess we can't use event.target and event.currentTarget as per mentioned here : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_base_events.htm. I tries using event.getSource() but that also does not work. What you guys are doing about this currently?

Answer (score 3):

LockerService tends to eat some "value" html attributes ( not on  but on other tags like divs for example )
To make sure it's kept, you should use data-value HTML attribute

`<li data-value="whatever" />`

Then to retrieve it, here is a sample of the code we use ( LS-proof ! )

```
var attr = 'data-value' ;

var res = null ;
var oTarget = event.target ;
if (oTarget.attributes[attr] != null)
        res = oTarget.attributes[attr].value;
else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < oTarget.attributes.length; i++)
        {
            if (oTarget.attributes[i].name === attr)
               res = oTarget.attributes[i].value ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Value is a supported attribute, as shown [here](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureElement.app?aura.mode=DEV). While not all elements support "value," the ones on this page that do should continue to do so.