# event target is empty

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I want to get index variable of `products` array record in controller on which user clicked. I am trying to get this by `event.target.dataset.index`. But `event.target.dataset.index` gives undefined. The code is as below:

Component

```
<ul>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="product" indexVar="index">
    <li onclick="{!c.ShowDataOnClick}" data-row-index="{!index}">
        <p>{!product.Name}</p>
        <p>{!product.ProductCode}</p>
    </li>
</aura:iteration></ul>
```

Controller

```
ShowDataOnClick: function(component, event, helper) {
    var index = event.target.dataset.index;
    console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: Try assigning `index` to a label attribute of `<li>` and access it in controller like this: `event.getSource().get("v.label");`

Comment: Hi Rohit, console returns: event.getSource is not a function.

Comment: Hope this helps: [event-getsource-on-onclick-from-li](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176443/event-getsource-on-onclick-from-li)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Component:**

```
<aura:application >
    <ul>
        <aura:iteration items="[1,2,3,4]" var="product" indexVar="index">
            <li onclick="{!c.ShowDataOnClick}" data-row-index="{!index}">
                <p>{!product}</p>
                <p>{!product}</p>
            </li>
        </aura:iteration></ul>
</aura:application>
```

use `currentTarget` instead of <s>`target`</s>

**controller:**

```
 ({
        ShowDataOnClick: function(component, event, helper) {
           var index = event.currentTarget.dataset.rowIndex;
            console.log(index);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Already tried. event.currentTarget gives Proxy {} and event.currentTarget.dataset.index gives undefined.

Comment: I have tried just I am getting value correctly .open the proxy  object see dataset check whether  its have a index.

Comment: Hi,  I open proxy object. It show the following value in dataset.
dataset:Proxy
-> [[Handler]]:a
-> __proto__:Object
-> [[Target]]:d
-> [[IsRevoked]]:false

Comment: Proxy {$actual$: DOMStringMap}
[[Handler]]
:
a
[[Target]]
:
d
$actual$
:
DOMStringMap
auraRenderedBy
:
"15:0"
index
:
"2"
__proto__
:
DOMStringMap
__proto__
:
Object
[[IsRevoked]]
:
false

Comment: No. No sign of index.

Comment: Checked again in sub-objects also. No sign of index. Am I missing something?

Comment: I worked similar example I am getting index correctly see the edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62578/discussion-between-vignesh-and-jigar-trivedi).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue is that the event parameter changes depending on the element being clicked.

So if you are clicking on `{!product}` and it is firing the function on the parent `li` element, the event parameter for the parent function is actually set to the `p` element of the product.

There should be a way to get the exact element triggering the function, especially when we cannot manually set function input parameters.

EDIT: Turns out you can, use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.